# Why does my variable keep adding in firestore without stopping?

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I am tring to get my arraylist to work and I have managed to get it inserted into firestore without any problems in my other activity class but not in this one.. I don't understand why it keeps adding it to firestore or just won't stop... From my understanding, must we always use the information class to set our setters?

```
  enter code he     DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://medical-review-in-australia.firebaseio.com/").getReference().child("Medical Clinics");
                reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                       // for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                         //   don 't need a loop when inserting data in firebase..


                            String clinic_name = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("Name").getValue());
                            String clinic_name2 = clinic_name.toLowerCase();

                        ArrayList<String> ranking;
                            ArrayList<String> badWords = null;

                            badWords = new ArrayList<>();
                            badWords.add("stupid");
                            badWords.add("fuck");
                            badWords.add("fucking");
                            badWords.add("shit");
                            badWords.add("asshole");
                            badWords.add("nigga");
                            badWords.add("retard");
                            badWords.add("sex");
                            badWords.add("breasts");
                            badWords.add("penis");
                            for (int i = 0; i < badWords.size(); i++) {
                                String badWord = badWords.get(i);
                                if (txt_name.toLowerCase().contains(badWord) || txt_address.toLowerCase().contains(badWord) || txt_suburb.toLowerCase().contains(badWord) || txt_state.toLowerCase().contains(badWord) || postcode2.toLowerCase().contains(badWord) || txt_doctor.toLowerCase().contains(badWord)) {
                                    //     txt_review = txt_review.replace(badWord, "*****");
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Make sure that it does not contain any rude words", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    return;
                                }
                            }


                            if (clinic_name.equals(txt_name) || clinic_name2.equals(txt_name)) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Medical Clinic already exists in the database!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (txt_name.isEmpty() || txt_address.isEmpty() || phone.isEmpty() || txt_suburb.isEmpty() || txt_state.isEmpty() || postcode2.isEmpty() || txt_doctor.isEmpty()) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Make sure you have completed all fields and also make sure they are bulk billing clinics!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else if (phone.length() != 8) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Make sure the phone number contains the correct number of digits!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            } else {
                                ranking = new ArrayList<>();
                                ranking.add("Gumshoe");
                                information.setName(txt_name);
                                information.setAddress(txt_address);
                                information.setPhone_No(phone);
                                information.setSuburb(txt_suburb);
                                information.setState(txt_state);
                                information.setPostcode(postcode2);
                                information.setDoctor(txt_doctor);
                                information.setTotal_Score(total_score);
                                information.setRanking(ranking);

                                  //    HashMap<String, Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                                  //       user.put("Medical Clinics", information);
                                  //       user.put("address", txt_address);
                                  //      user.put("phone_No", phone);
                                  //     user.put("suburb", txt_suburb);
                                  //     user.put("state", txt_state);
                                  //    user.put("postcode", postcode2);
                                  //    user.put("doctor", txt_doctor);
                             //         user.put("ranking", ranking);
                                 //   user.put("total Score", total_score);




                              //  HashMap<String, Arra> user2 = new HashMap<>();
                           //     user2.put("ranking", ranking);







                                //     reff.setValue(information);






                        //        rank.setText("Your current rank: " + ranking);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Information has been added successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                System.out.println(ranking);
                                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://medical-review-in-australia.firebaseio.com/").getReference().child("Medical Clinics").child(txt_name).setValue(user);

//
                            //    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://medical-review-in-australia.firebaseio.com/").getReference().child("Medical Clinics").child(txt_name).child("ranking").setValue(user);
                           //     System.out.println(ranking);
                                //

                                //         FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://medical-review-in-australia.firebaseio.com/").getReference().child(txt_name).child("Total Score").setValue(total_score);


[enter image description here][1]
```